# How to use Python's type hints with decorated functions and generators?

Tags: python, decorator, static-typing

Suppose I have the following code, using `twisted`'s `defer.inlineCallbacks`:

```
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor

def main() -> None:
    reactor.callWhenRunning(
        lambda: main_task().addBoth(
            lambda _: reactor.stop()))
    reactor.run()

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main_task():
    data = yield fetch_a_lot_of_data()
    yield write_data_to_disk(data)
    defer.returnValue(None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The body of `main_task` does not return anything, but `main_task` actually returns a generator that yields `defer.Deferred` objects... which the `@defer.inlineCallbacks` decorator uses to instead make function that returns another `defer.Deferred` object

So how should I annotate `main_task`'s return value?

- `def main_task() -> None:`, the result of the task?
- `def main_task() -> Generator[defer.Deferred, object, None]:`, the return value of main_task if it didn't have a decorator on it?
- `def main_task() -> defer.Deferred:`, the return value of the decorated function?

...or something else entirely?

Comment: I don't see anything about this case in the [type hinting PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). Someone more familiar with mypy might be able to give some input on how mypy handles it.